# Pattern search in python

Tags: python, regex

Following is my code -

```
line = Application::load( ppv ) launchUri: package://C2FF73A0-D18AACEB/ppv.html
n = re.search(r"Application::load\( (.*?) \)",line)

print n.groups()
```

Its giving output like -

```
('ppv',)
```

I need just ppv as a output.

Will anyone suggest me what modification I should do to get expected output?

Answer (score 5):

Change `print n.groups()` to `print n.group(1)`.

[`Match.group(n)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) will return the nth group from the regex, or if `n` is not provided or `0` then the entire match will be returned.